# Scheduled query stopped writing to table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several scheduled queries running in BigQuery but some have stopped writing to destination tables even though run history shows the queries ran and the queries work when run manually. There's no error message or other indication that something is broken with the scheduled queries. I've tried rescheduling, recreating scheduled queries, replacing destination tables, adding additional permissions (I'm already a project admin and owner) and updating credentials. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: If dest table doesn't exist before scheduled query, would the scheduled query create a new one at all?

Comment: The destination tables do exist and were getting overwritten or appended as expected until a couple weeks ago, so I know these scheduled jobs can work but am not sure why they stopped working and BQ still showing successful runs so no errors to go off of.

Comment: Maybe you can create a bug here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers, with the job id of scheduled query with expected results (maybe one job id with expected results) to get some help.